# Debugging Android Package Manager API

Tags: android, android-source, android-package-managers

I am trying to understand the working details of the [Package Manager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) on Android. I'm using Android Studio to debug it. I have built the AOSP code and am running it on an emulator. Android Studio provides a way to attach to Android processes; however, I am not sure which process to connect to to debug the PackageManager. I assumed the name of the process would be com.android.packageinstaller, but it never shows up on the list of debuggable processes, even when I try to install an apk on the side via adb although my print lines in the AOSP code seems to show up (which means the process is running). Could somebody please explain me how I should be going about debugging the Package Manager? Which process should I be connecting to?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

The Package Manager as well as many other critical services are built off of `frameworks/base/services/` (see: http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/) into a `services.jar` artifact which is a library (http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/Android.mk#7) and not an app.

The "app" that runs this code happens to be a custom instantiation of the core Dalvik virtual machine that you'll find in Zygote.java (the "Main" class for the Dalvik VM). See here: http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/os/ZygoteInit.java#514.

When the Zygote process (the root process of all Android *Java* processes) is started it is named `app_process` but when started for running the core system services, then it is run with a special command line argument that causes it to call itself `system_server`.

So if you want to debug the Package Manager code, best is to attach to that process. You might also consider sprinkling log statements into the package manager code in the framework and looking at those as well or instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to the `system_process`. Most of the core services that compose Android all run in that process.